# Running below c++ program

Tags: c++

I have recently started coding in c++ and when I run below code it runs fine

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &numbers, int target){
        vector<int> result;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j =i+1 ; j<numbers.size(); j++){
                if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]){
                    result.push_back (i);
                    result.push_back (j);
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
    }
    
};
```

whereas for this one it gives

```
Line 15: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
 1 error generated.
```

I am not sure why because both are same

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &numbers, int target){
        vector<int> result;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j =i+1 ; j<numbers.size(); j++){
                if (numbers[j] == target - numbers[i]){
                    result.push_back (i);
                    result.push_back (j);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
};
```

Comment: The error is correct for the second code sample. What does your function return if the size of the vector is 0? Also they may produce a different result. I mean the second exits the function on the first occurrence where the if condition is true.

Comment: they aren't the same, one has a `return` at the end of the function the other only returns inside an if statement

Comment: Because the function is supposed to return a value and the below code is only returning something only when a condition is met. If that condition never comes to pass then the function will return nothing i.e., void but that thing do not match the function declaration so therefore it gives you that error.

Comment: If the `if` in the second example never evaluates to true, the function doesn't return a value

Comment: What if the `if` statement fails all the time, it returns nothing however non-void function should return something.

Answer (score 1):

Both your codes are not the same.

In your first code, the `return` statement is placed *after* the nested for loop, so that it will always be executed when the function `twoSum()` is called.

However, in your second the code example, the `return` statement is enclosed within an `if` statement and so will *only* execute **if** the condition within the `if` statement is statisfied.

Therefore from a compiler's perspective, it is possible (in your second code) that the expression in the `if` statement never evaluates to `true` and so the `return` statement **may** never be executed.

You can correct your second code by adding a `return` statement at the end of your function, like in your first piece of code.